# Wait for a webpage to be displayed then launch another URL in web borwser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a winform that holds a `WebBowser` control, what I am wanting is for this to display a Webpage I have, however the issue is before the webpage can be displayed two other url's need to be launched.

Unfortuntely, due to this when I am calling the urls this is failing to navigate because only one of the URLs is being called.

I have tied the following:

```
        this.WebBox.Navigate(URL1);
        this.WebBox.Navigate(URL2);
        this.WebBox.Navigate(URL3);
```

Also

having a for loop and adding these values to an array

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= AllURLS.Count; i++)
        {
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WebBox.Navigate(AllURLS.ToString()));
            task.Wait();
        }
```

Any help on how to achive this would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can change your code to wait fully loaded.

```
this.WebBox.Navigate(URL1);
while(this.WebBox.Navigate.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
     Application.DoEvents();
}
this.WebBox.Navigate(URL2);
while(this.WebBox.Navigate.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
     Application.DoEvents();
}
this.WebBox.Navigate(URL3);
while(this.WebBox.Navigate.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
     Application.DoEvents();
}
//Done!
```

Hope this will help you !

Comment: Your wellcome! If this worked for you, please mark as answer :)